# Redirect after Login MyWSAT

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I've been testing the example code here http://mywsat.codeplex.com/

In their example they have different buttons to login to either the `admin` pages or `members` page using seperate links

However, I'm trying to use a single link to a landing page and after the user logs in  redirect to the relevant page using codebehind. The landingpage requires login but all roles can view this page set in the rules.

**landingpage.aspx:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string redirectPath;
        string pagePath = Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath;
        if (Page.User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
        {
            //Admin
            redirectPath = "~/admin/Default.aspx";
            if (redirectPath != pagePath)
            {
                Response.Redirect(redirectPath);
            }
        }
        else if (Page.User.IsInRole("Member"))
        {
            //Members
            redirectPath = "~/members/Default.aspx";
            if (redirectPath != pagePath)
            {
                Response.Redirect(redirectPath);
            }
        }
        else if (Page.User.IsInRole("Trial"))
        {
            //Trial
            redirectPath = "~/trial/Default.aspx";
            if (redirectPath != pagePath)
            {
                Response.Redirect(redirectPath);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Non member
            redirectPath = "~/Default.aspx";
            if (redirectPath != pagePath)
            {
                Response.Redirect(redirectPath);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is the Page_Load event fires straight away and then launches `login-with-captcha.ascx` after the event has fired.

So then I moved the code to the login form `login-with-captcha.ascx.cs` to redirect after  `e.Authenticated = true;` but it just redirects back to `login-with-captcha.ascx` in an endless loop

**login-with-captcha.ascx.cs:**

```
       // Next, determine if the user's username/password are valid
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(loginUsername, loginPassword))
        {
            e.Authenticated = true;
            //tried redirecting from here based on role!
        }
        else
        //............
```

How can I redirect from the landing page after the user is validated? I suspect it may have something to do with postback but need some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try adding the following as the first line within your Page_Load to see if it helps? This will likely prevent the endless loop issue if it's being caused by something that triggers a postback event, like a button click.

```
if (IsPostBack) return;
```